# Angular routeProvider named groups not working?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code. I'm trying to get it to match any url. If I replace /*path with /:something/:somethingelse and visit /asdf/asdf it will work, but it won't match anything at all using /*path. Everything I've been able to find indicates this is the proper syntax.

I'm using angular 1.2.18, and have tried the bleeding edge beta release as well.

Does anyone know what I might be running into here?

EDIT: Here's a fiddle showing it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/2hYK9/

```
window.MyApp = MyApp = angular.module 'MyApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngTouch']

MyApp.config ['$locationProvider', ($locationProvider) ->
    $locationProvider.html5Mode true
]

MyApp.config ['$routeProvider',
    ($routeProvider, $routeParams, $location) ->
        $routeProvider.
            when("/*path", {
                templateUrl: (path) ->
                    console.log path
                    return '/pages/asdf.html'
                ,
                controller: 'BrowseController',
                reloadOnSearch: false
            })
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct syntax is `:path*`.

From [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider):

> path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a
>   star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams
>   under the given name when the route matches.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I feel dumb. All the other results had links to old version of the docs, and how this works changed.

This is correct syntax now:

/:path*